# mat-error doesn't show that it is an error message?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
ts
formControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z_-]$/),
    Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(32)
  ]);

  errorMessage(): any {
    if (this.formControl.hasError('required')) {
      return 'You must enter a value';
    } else if (this.formControl.hasError('pattern')) {
      return 'Username can only be letters,underscores and horizontal lines';
    }
  }
```

```
html
<mat-error>{{errorMessage()}}</mat-error>
```

1. `this.formControl.hasError('required')` It's works
2. `this.formControl.hasError('pattern')` It isn't works

I checked the angular-material document, but did not find the usage.
Why does it produce such a result？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the pattern you have provided. The correct pattern would be `/^[a-zA-Z_-]{5,32}$/`. Note the length in the pattern.

You `formControl` code would be following:

```
  formControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required, 
    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z_-]{5,32}$/),
    Validators.minLength(5), 
    Validators.maxLength(32)
  ]);
```

And you should also put a condition on `mat-error` so that it is only rendered when the control is invalid. Like this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="formControl.invalid">{{errorMessage()}}</mat-error>
```

Link to [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ek33t5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Literal notation (slashes) is allowed, because Validators.pattern accepts RegExp: `static pattern(pattern: string | RegExp): ValidatorFn;`

Comment: @JohnMalkoln, you are right. I have updated the answer & demo.